# Renaming values in a column based on predefined ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of years in a column (pandas)

```
Year
2001
2002
2018
2002
2006
2010
2019
2010
```

I would like to visualise in a bar chart how many years are by 2012 and how many years there are after 2012, i.e. I should have in my column something like this:

```
Year
<2012
<2012
>2012
<2012
<2012
<2012
>2012
<2012
```

in order to plot the total of values before/after 2012.
I tried something like this:

```
df.replace([1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, ... ], ["<2012", "<2012", "<2012", "<2012","<2012"])
```

similarly for years > 2020.

Can you please tell me how to rename the observation in an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
pd.cut(df['Year'], bins=[-np.inf, 2012, np.inf], labels=['<2012', '>2012'])

0    <2012
1    <2012
2    >2012
3    <2012
4    <2012
5    <2012
6    >2012
7    <2012
Name: Year, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['<2012' < '>2012']
```

---

Add more bins like this:

```
pd.cut(df['Year'], 
       bins=[-np.inf, 2012, 2020, ..., np.inf], 
       labels=['<2012', '<2020', ...])
```

Comment: thanks cs95. Quick question: would it be possible to plot these values, though they are not numeric?

Comment: @Val I guess it depends on what you're trying to visualize.

Comment: just a histogram with two bars, one for values with category <2012 and another one with values >=2012

Comment: @Val I think plot.bar() or plot.hist() would work. I recommend searching for pandas Visualization docs to get an idea of the functions available to you.